# 10 threads write to single hash simultaniously

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry for the question(( I just have stuck in the end of the day((
I need for test 10 threads writing to the same hash (really not a hash but very similar thing i need to prove it synchronization for write)
is this is right code?

```
Random rn = new Random();

Map<int,int> hash = new MyHashMap<int,int>();

for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
 Thread th = new MyAddingThread();
 th.Start();
}

public class MyAddingThread extends Thread{
 public void run()
 {
   hash.Add(rn.nextInt,rn.nextInt);
 }
}
```

May be better to change 10 to 100. but I have no idea how to test dat hash for synchronization(

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i< 11; i++)` will loop 11 times, not 10

Comment: I wonder what's the real problem you're facing. Creating a thread to just do a single `hash.put` is not really efficient. Explain the big picture to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether `hash` is thread-safe or not? There really is no reliable way to do so. Multi-thread development can introduce any number of bugs that can be extremely difficult to detect. A data structure is either designed to be thread-safe, or it is not.

Comment: What do you really want to test? Using a simple HashMap concurrently can result in corrupt data structures which create endless loops on access!

Comment: Is this real Java? Looks more like C# to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work, as all threads should try to add the item to the hash at the same time.

To do that, you need to use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

```
[[main]]
CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
 Thread th = new MyAddingThread();
 th.Start();
}
startSignal.countdown();


[[on the thread]]    
public class MyAddingThread extends Thread{
 public void run()
 {
   startSignal.await();
   hash.Add(rn.nextInt,rn.nextInt);
 }
}
```

The javadoc of this class has a similar (but more complex) example.

Also, if you want to test this properly, create the same number of threads as cores in your computer and each thread should do a loop and insert a few hundred items at least. if you try to only insert 10 elements, there are very little chances that you'll hit a concurrent problem.

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap` is not thread-safe. Use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead.

**EDIT**

If your real question is whether your code will allow you to test whether any given data structure is thread-safe or not, there really is no reliable way to do so. Multi-thread development can introduce any number of bugs that can be extremely difficult to detect. A data structure is either designed to be thread-safe, or it is not.

Comment: quoted from the question **I need for test 10 threads writing to the same hash (really not a hash but very similar thing i need to prove it synchronization for write**. He's not using a java HashMap.

Comment: i nned to test it - this is problem. the class is very similar to hash map but it is belief as thread safe - I need to proof that this is lie

Comment: It really depends on the data structure to which you are writing. Some are thread-safe, some are not. (You could always put the write operations inside a `synchronized` block to be extra-safe, at the expense of performance)

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` is **not** synchronized so you have to do it on your own!

You may synchronize the access:

```
public class MyAddingThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    synchronized(hash) {
      hash.put(rn.nextInt(),rn.nextInt());
    }
  }
}
```

but than you miss most of the concurrent execution.

Another idea is to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer,Integer> hash = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public class MyAddingThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    hash.put(rn.nextInt(),rn.nextInt());
  }
}
```

This would give more performance due to less blocking code.

The other problem is the use of `Random` here which is thread safe but will also result in poor performance.

Which solution is the best for your problem I cannot consider from your little pseudo code.